# Problem with Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using a [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) modem to connect to the Internet. I can connect with mobile phone and laptop without problem but when I use a PC with Wi-Fi USB I connect to the network but I don't have data from the Internet. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your software firewall temporarily; does it solve the problem?

Are you getting an IP address from the modem? Maybe you have a static IP set.

Can you ping IP addresses but not surf names?

Can you ping the modem's IP address?